# Progressbar Scene Builder

Tags: nullpointerexception, progress-bar, fxml

I found similar problem here but the solution for that didn't resolve my problem.
The link for the similar problem is here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419590/use-progressbar-made-with-fxml-scenebuilder-to-use-values-from-a-method).
Well about my problem, progressbar won't update when I click on the radio button.

my fxml file for that scene is here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
 <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
 <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
 <?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="468.0" prefWidth="972.0" style="-fx-
background-color: #02b496;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="Controllers.RegisterController">
<children>
  <ImageView fitHeight="497.0" fitWidth="972.0" opacity="0.68" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@LogInPic.jpg" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <AnchorPane id="registration" fx:id="registration" layoutX="544.0" layoutY="49.0" opacity="0.91" prefHeight="357.0" prefWidth="359.0" style="-fx-background-color: orange;">
     <children>
        <Text layoutX="94.0" layoutY="44.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sign Up" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="133.5869140625">
           <font>
              <Font size="18.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
        <Text layoutX="30.0" layoutY="107.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome to register pane " wrappingWidth="189.13671875">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
        <RadioButton fx:id="menadzer" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="195.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleMenadzerBtn" text="Manager" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="kupac" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="195.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleKupacBtn" text="Customer" />
        <Text layoutX="30.0" layoutY="146.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Before you start registration choose one of the following" wrappingWidth="226.283203125">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
        <Text layoutX="30.0" layoutY="257.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Registartion procces completion">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Text>
        <Button layoutX="246.0" layoutY="270.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBackBtn" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: #df8020;" text="Back">
           <font>
              <Font size="15.0" />
           </font>
        </Button>
        <ProgressBar fx:id="pb" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="273.0" 
opacity="0.57" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" />
     </children>
    </AnchorPane>
    </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

My controller class

In this class i am setting progress to my bar and its trowing me null pointer exception, i really cant find where the problem is so i need you help.

```
   public class RegisterController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ProgressBar pb;


@FXML
private void handleMenadzerBtn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    pb.setProgress(0.1);
    long mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = mTime + 2000;

    while (mTime < end) {
        mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/Home.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {  
 }
}
```

The error code i am gettig is here :

```
   Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton.fire(ToggleButton.java:256)
at javafx.scene.control.RadioButton.fire(RadioButton.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 49 more
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controllers.RegisterController.handleMenadzerBtn(RegisterController.java:41)
... 59 more
 Feb 13, 2018 4:19:42 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
  WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX 
  runtime of version 8.0.101
```

So if someone could help, i would be thankful, if you need some more material just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the error at this line

```
pb.setProgress(0.1);
```

Because your ProgressBar is null. You have to initialize ProgressBar before using the object of ProgressBar.